# Help on how to create a hologram with particles

Tags: particles

I'm working on a hologram and want particles to flow from the hologram source to the hologram and then fade out.

I have tried lots of things and watched all tutorials I could find but I can not make it work. The closest I seen a tutorial on was to use the harmonious forcefield to gather the particles from Susan to the point where the hologram source was. 
2 problems with that. First is that I did as they did in the tutorial but I could not make it work. The froce field did not affect the particles. Second is that the particles flows the wrong way like that. From the hologram to the sorce and not as it should be from the source to the hologram.

I appreciate if someone could help me with how to set this up.

---

Edit to add requested info:

Almost like this.

In this tutorial the particles flow from the circle below up to Susan. Thats good. But the particles flows from the whole surface and straight up. I want the particles to go from one small point and spread out up to the hologram and that way create the lightcone in this picture.

The guy who made this used several lightsourses to make the lightcone make the ambiance of the image but I need to avoid lights for this project.

The closest I come trying to figure this out is to use the harmonic force field to drag the particles into a cone. I seen it done before but I can not make that happen. The forcefield do not attract the particles.

[image]

Tutorial made by MattSmith1995 found on Youtube

Comment: Reference animation/images. Those could help us a lot to understand your question.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add reference [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand what you are after.

Comment: If you want one flow of particles that go up to create the hologram, you can dissolve the object like [here](http://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/394-tutorial-dissolve-your-logo-in-blender-262.html) and then reverse the rendered animation in the final video edit. A force field  of type force with a negative strength will pull the particles to it. You may want to look into keyed particles, like [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33108/935) or [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21580/935).

Answer (score 1):

[image: sample particles]

- You want the particles to travel upwards. Set the [particles Field Weight for gravity](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/force_field.html#field-weights) to 0.0. Add a [force field](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/force_fields/types/force.html) at the location of suzanne with a negative strength, or you could assign the force field settings to the model itself. Setting the shape to plane seems to worked best.
- To make them move slower, increase the [mass for the particles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/physics/newtonian.html).
- To make them disappear as they pass suzanne. You can [enable collision](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/collision.html#options) for the object with kill particles enabled. Also adjust the lifetime so that the longest lived particles finish just above the object.
- You want the particles to emit from a small area. Here you have a couple of options, one is to add a small object at the point to emit the particles. Another option that I used, is to assign some vertices (or a single vertex) from the object at the location of emission to a [vertex group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html) that you then select in the particles [vertex groups for density](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/vertex_groups.html). I also shaped the verts into a small pyramid to get the particles to spread outwards a bit more, a little random velocity also helped with that.

[Here is a sample file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49794)